# $_SERVER[HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] set to NO CACHE always even though cache on

Tags: php, meta-tags

I checked `$_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']` and it is saying `no cache` even though i have the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">
```

and I've tried this as well

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="cache">
```

still saying same "No CACHE"

Should I be worried that search engine spider gets same value as `$_SERVER`?

Answer (score 2):

That value refers to the `Cache-Control` HTTP header sent in the **request**, i.e. the client sent this information to you. You have no control over it, but it doesn't have any real influence on your server either.